# issue with profileTemplate in selenium server

Tags: selenium

I try to use Firefox Template to specify some parameters in prefs.js file.
I use two scenarios

1. test with webdriver
   Code:

   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("/home/user/selenium.default"));
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

   Result: works as expected
2. test with remoteWebDriver

   Steps:

   1. start selenium server

      ```
      java -jar selenium-server-standalo-2.19.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -firefoxProfileTemplate /home/user/selenium.default/ -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/home/user/Apps/firefox/firefox
      ```
   2. code on client side

      ```
      DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
      ```

   Result: browser start, but not implement settings specified in pref.js. So, not load profile from specified directory.

Have someone succes with profileTemplate in selenium server?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter -firefoxProfileTemplate is not working anymore.
In current versions its: -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile="name".

With name just being the name and not the whole path.

See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2571

Answer (score 0):

What I know you have to write the full profilePath for Firefox like:
`-firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\ffprofile"`.

- Maybe another reason:

Try:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("path_to_profile");
cap.SetCapability("firefox_profile", profile.ToBase64String());
```